# RPC to sign PSBT with private key

Tags: signature, signrawtransaction, bip174-psbt

What is the PSBT related RPC which works similar to [signrawtransactionwithkey](https://bitcoincore.org/en/doc/0.21.0/rpc/rawtransactions/signrawtransactionwithkey/) ?

Comment: There currently isn't one.

Comment: Thanks. So I assume `walletprocessbt` is the only way to sign PSBT right now.